# Change image source based on screensize

Tags: jquery, replace, responsive-design, attr

I'm trying to get a script working.

I have some images:

- image-270x572.gif
- image-220x466.gif (default)
- image-166x352.gif

The goal here is that on a screen larger than 1200px it replaces the 220x446 in 270x572 and for screens smaller than 980 it replaces 220x446 to 166x352.

I think this is pretty basic jQuery but im such a noob with this, can't get it to work.

This is what I got:

```
if($(window).width() > 1199) {
    $('.slider .img').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        element.attr('src', src.replace('270','572')); 
   });
}
```

And than the same for the other sizes.... guessing its all wrong.

Would love some help, thanks.
/Paul

Comment: Do you get errors in console? Since you haven't close bracket in the code you provided.

Comment: It could be also made with css media queries http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by _guessing its all wrong_ . Is there any error or issue you are facing?

Comment: @ArthurHalma well, no but it's just not doing a thing. I did close it on my end. Did added it here, thanks.

Comment: @matty I know, but the images are uploaded via a CMS + they are in a slider so that is not an option.

Comment: @PalashMondal I'm not successful in replaceing 220x466 in 270x572 for example. So I think the element.attr('src', src.replace('270','572')); is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing a string that doesnt exist.

When I get you right, all images have an initial source url of "image-220x466.gif". In your function, you replace this string's '270' parts with '572', which can not work since there is no "270" in "image-220x466.gif".

I am not sure why you cant just set the source directly, like so:

```
element.attr('src', 'image-270x572.gif');
```

**EDIT**

change __ x __ for each resolution:

```
$('.slider .img').each(function() {
    var element = $(this),
        src = $(this).attr('src'),
        newSrc;

   if ( $(window).width() > 1199) {
    newSrc = src.replace('220', '270');
    newSrc = src.replace('466', '572');
   }
   else if () {

   }
   else if () {

   }

   element.attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

There seems to be some lack of understanding what .replace() does. In brief, replace takes two parameters. The first one is the string that shall be replaced and the second one defines what shall be inserted instead.

So if your string is "220x466" you can replace the 220 with something else, like so:

```
"220x466".replace("220", "270");
```

will will output `"270x466"`

Comment: due images are uploaded via cms the filename is dynamic. The measurement in the filename are not, they are always stated as above.

Comment: that info would have been great before :) wait for edit answer then

Comment: ooooooh the '270','572' is the 1th and 2nd measurement in the filename is it?

Answer (score 1):

My code. It has one limitation - filename must be with only one "-" - that splitting name and size.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/Gg79q/

```
if($(window).width() > 1199) {
    $('.slider .img').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var src = element.attr('src');
        var name = src.split("-");
        var ext = name[name.length-1];
        ext = (ext.split("."))[1];
        name = name[0];
        var newSize = "270x572";
        var newSrc = name + "-" + newSize + "." + ext;
        alert(newSrc);
        element.attr('src', newSrc); 
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is '.img' a class that you have applied to your images or is it '.slider' or is it both? If it's '.slider' which has been applied to all the images that you want to change, here is how you can go about it:

```
$(function(){
  $(".slider").each(function(){
     var current = $(this).attr("src");
     var newSrc = current.replace('270', '572');
     $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
  });
});
```

I am using two variables to help you understand my answer better. You could combine those lines into one without using the vars.

Answer (score -1):

I've make example at `jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/kw2V8/`

. Please check out!

Comment: Please also post the code of your answer here. Now we have to copy/paste your URL to have a look at it, while StackOverflow itself is perfect for posting code.